# Package.json role in packaging for distribution

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, quasar-framework, electron-packager

I am confused on the role of package.json as far as packaging is concerned.

AFAIK, those under `dependencies` will be included in the distribution package and those under `devDependencies` will not be included.

However, I did an experiment to try to minimize the package size of the application. I removed all `dependencies` and `devDependencies` and as expected, node_modules were not included in the package anymore (not in dist/resources). But when I tried running the packaged application, it still worked. All those functionalities that required node_modules still worked.

Is this normal? Or was there an application in the framework that caused this behavior (e.g. webpack, babel, etc)?

I am using Quasar framework for Electron development and Electron-packager (built in on the Quasar framework) for packaging.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the 'node_modules' folder manually before building? It could be that if the folders are there locally and you did a build your app can still find them.